# How to unlock seat belts on Toyota Land Cruiser 200

Tags: toyota, seat-belt

I heve Toyota Land Cruiser 200 (2008 year). After hard braking the passengers seat belt get locked by belt tensioner for some reason (there was no passenger) and I can't get it unlocked. The seat belt is in the lowest possible position so it is impossible to unlock it in ordinary way and I don't want to disassemble it. There is rumors amount TLC owners that you can unlock them by some tricky order of buttons but no one knows exactly.
Any ideas how to unlock them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same thing happened to my '00 Tundra.  Locking pawl got stuck when it was engaged.  There was sand/grit/goo in the mechanism.
Don't know if the setup is the same, but undo the 3 bolts on the belt reel cover, clean the locking mechanism (I used WD-40, rags and an old toothbrush), regrease and reinstall the cover.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure it's not electrical. I can't speak to the land cruiser but I've replaced seat belts on a 2000 Tacoma, and there is some kind of relay activated by a small wiring harness. Basically if that is not plugged in, the reel will be completely locked. Maybe yours came loose or otherwise broke the circuit.

Comment: It turns out the issue with electrics. Some of the fuses in the fuse box were oxidized heavily. I found it after a lot of other glitches with electrics start to appear.